# Macro to update table from form in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access form linked to an MS Access table.  Whenever the form is filled, the table will be populated only if I close the database.

I have a dummy "SUBMIT" button on the form, and I want to be able to populate my table from the form on the click of this button and clear the form for new entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the table as the row source of your form in the properties(design View).
Or you could make a query that uses insert to make new records in your table and fill them with the values from your form, like this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable( [User], [Name] ) 
SELECT [Forms]![YourForm]![Uservalue] AS [User], [Forms]![YourForm]![NameValue] AS [Name];
```

Then put an event procedure in the OnClick event of the SUBMIT button that calls the query(VBA)

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "YourQuery"
```

Or to run the SQL code straight from VBA.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "YourSQL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Data in an Access bound form WILL NOT write the data to the table until you close the database or close the form, or navigate to a new record.

However,  you can simply place a submit button on the form.
So the code behind the submit button would be:

```
' code to submit data to table:
Me.Dirty = false
```

The above code will case the form to submit and write the data to the forms underlying table. So YOU CAN write code to submit the forms data if you wish. It is only one line.

If the user closes the form, or closes the database and they NOT hit submit, then what do you want to do? You have to explain what you want to occur in this case. If you do nothing, then Access will automatically submit the data to the table for you. Or perhaps you want to nag and torture the user and prompt them as to what to do? And if you say no to not save data, do you want to return back to the form, or continue closing that form? (the user will think if they hit no to not save, then they are asking for a chance to edit the form data some more, and not discard the data entry they done so for).

You also not explain after the user hits submit more then one time, then what you want to occur? If the user accidently hits the submit button two times (REALLY EASY say with a double mouse click, then do you want the forms data to be written to the table two times?

So there is HUGE HUGE number of questions you not answered here.

So if the user does not hit submit, but closes the form (or database), what do you want to occur?

If the user by accident hits submit two times, do you want the data to be written to the table two times? What do you want to happen here? What will stop user from hitting submit multiple times and not resulting in multiple reocrds?

So keep in mind that ONE LINE of code behind the button called submit will submit the data to the table, but it it’s the 100+ other details as to what supposed to occur when user’s hit submit more then once, and what occurs when closing the form without having hit submit is the details you not yet shared. And not only is there closing of the form, but what about closing the application?

So keep in mind ONLY ONE LINE of code is required to submit the data to the table and that code is:

```
Me.Dirty = false
```